# How to parse a line by line in python and put multiple values in a tuple

Tags: python, parsing, tuples

Each line have this form:

```
[id=52, idRegion=3857, tipo=New, CustomerDetails=[id=10, countryCode=DE, ... and so on
```

What I want to accomplish is to read line by line a make a tuple with values of id, idRegion and so on like this

```
(52,3857,New,10,DE ....), (another line with tuple).... to later to put in an excel
```

I've tried this, but it seems too far of what i want:

```
a = re.findall( "id=(\d+),.idRegion=\d+, tipo=.*?,", file_txt)
b = re.findall( "id=\d+,.idRegion=(\d+),.tipo=.*?,", file_txt)
c = re.findall( "id=\d+,.idRegion=\d+,.tipo=(.*?),", file_txt)
d = [tuple(j for j in i if j)[-1] for i in a,b,c]
print c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know much about your input data format. Assuming your keys consist of alphanumeric characters only and values consist of alphanumerics and spaces, you can use `\w+=([\w\s]+?)[,\]]` regular expression to capture the values. Apply the expression via `re.findall()` against every next line:

```
import re


data = """
[id=52, idRegion=3857, tipo=New, CustomerDetails=[id=10, countryCode=DE]
[id=100, idRegion=11, tipo=New Something, CustomerDetails=[id=20, countryCode=DE]
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"\w+=([\w\s]+?)[,\]]")

print([
    tuple(pattern.findall(line)) for line in data.splitlines() if line
])
```

Prints:

```
[
    ('52', '3857', 'New', '10', 'DE'), 
    ('100', '11', 'New Something', '20', 'DE')
]
```

Comment: works very well, but some fields have multiple word for example tipo=New Something, how can I modify to capture all the words after = and until the next comma ?

Comment: @BlueDotRo okay, updated with the new version that handles spaces as well.